# Why do python tuples need at least one comma?

Tags: python

If I want to create a tuple with only one value, I need to put a comma after it:

```
(value,)
```

While

```
(value)
```

is the same as

```
value
```

Why does python have this syntax? But isn't it redundant? Why not just use () for tuples only?

Comment: The comma creates the tuple, not the paranthesis

Comment: Yeah, I know. What I'm asking is why. Why not make  () be tuples as [] are lists?

Comment: You can use parentheses to group parts of an expression together to make the associativity clear (or make it different from the default). Do you think `(1+(2+3))` should create a tuple?

Comment: Because `(a+b)*2` and `(a)*2` should (probably) do similar things.

Comment: Python has a long history of using `()` to group expressions, such as in calculations, `(1+2)*3`.  And it isn't picky about whether those `()` are redundant or not.  The analogy with the list `[]` is not perfect.

Comment: I didn't know that saying "1,1" created a tuple. I thought that () was required to create tuples and forgot about the fact that () serves to group expressions as in math. Now everything makes sense!

Comment: `x = 1,` also creates a tuple.  Occasionally people try to use `,` as a line terminator, and unintentionally create a tuple.  `;` is ok as line terminator (but unneccsary).

Comment: @hpaulj though ```;``` is necessary if the commands are in the same line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parentheses are also used for expression grouping, like in the following example:

```
a + b * c
(a + b) * c
```

It would be hard and confusing to create a tuple when there's only one expression. Should the above example be treated as `tuple([a+b]) * c`? Probably not. Then how to distinguish between  `(value)` and `(value)`? Keep in mind that a value is also an expression.

On the other hand, you *don't* use brackets or braces to group expressions, so `[a]` and `[a, b]` have the same look. For convenience, `[a,]` is also valid and is identical to `[a]`.

That's why single-value tuples require an extra comma.